# jQuery onClick two functions how to merge

Tags: jquery, performance

this is my working code. but not in performance, 
can anyone guide me how to merge both scripts?

```
 $('input[value="landed-houses"]').on('change', function() {
   if($('input[value="landed-houses"]:checked').length > 0){
   $("div[data-target='#collapse-res-feat']").parent('div.panel-info').show(); 
  }
 else{
   $("div[data-target='#collapse-res-feat']").parent('div.panel-info').hide(); 
  }
 });

$('input[value="condominiums"]').on('change', function() {
   if($('input[value="condominiums"]:checked').length > 0){
   $("div[data-target='#collapse-res-feat']").parent('div.panel-info').show(); 
   }
 else{
   $("div[data-target='#collapse-res-feat']").parent('div.panel-info').hide(); 
  }
 });
```

thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask], it's not clear what you want and what your actual problem is.

Comment: are you trying to `show/hide` same div using two checkbox?? that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

if your question is how we merge the same event and event handle on two element, you can bind the document on that event and pass the selector in `.on` method of jQuery.

As you are trying to bind `change` event and your code for both `element` are same on change event.

```
if($('input[value="landed-houses"]:checked').length > 0){
   $("div[data-target='#collapse-res-feat']").parent('div.panel-info').show(); 
}
else{
   $("div[data-target='#collapse-res-feat']").parent('div.panel-info').hide(); 
 }
```

you can do something like

```
$(document).on('change',
    'input[value="condominiums"], input[value="landed-houses"]',  -- these are your selectors
    function(){
    }
)
```